# Norm of generator of prime ideal

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ be a cyclotomic field. For a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, we can write $\mathfrak{p} = (p,f_i(\zeta_n))$, where $\mathfrak{p}\cap\mathbb{Z}=p$ and and $f_i(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in the factorization of $\Phi_n(x)\bmod p$, where $\Phi_n(x)$ is the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. My question is: suppose $f_j(x)$, $i\ne j$, is another polynomial in the factorization of $\Phi_n(x)\bmod p$. Is it true that $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(f_i(\zeta_n)) = N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(f_j(\zeta_n))$?

Comment: Have you tried calculating any examples?

Comment: What method should I use to directly compute the norm of those elements?

Comment: You pick a number $n$, you pick a prime $p$, you factor $\Phi_n$ modulo $p$, you choose two of the irreducible factors, call them $f_i$ and $f_j$, you calculate the norms by multiplying together all the conjugates of $f_i(\zeta_n)$, and then all the conjugates of $f_j(\zeta_n)$.

Comment: For example, take $n=3$, $p=7$. Then $\Phi_n(x)=x^2+x+1$ which factors as $(x-2)(x-4)$ modulo seven. We can  take $f_1(\zeta_n)$ to be $\zeta_3-2$, and $f_2(\zeta_n)$ to be $\zeta_3-4$. Then you can calculate the norms. I get $7$ and $21$, which are not equal. But I didn't check to see what the prime ideal in $O_K$ is.

Comment: The norm of the prime ideal is $p^f$, where $f$ is the smallest integer such that $p^f\equiv 1 \bmod n$. Since $7\equiv 1\bmod 3$, the norm of the prime ideal is $7$. Regarding your calculation, since automorphisms of the field permute the prime ideals above $p\in\mathbb{Z}$, don't we have to have $\sigma(f_1(\zeta_n)) = f_2(\zeta_n)$ in the case, with $\sigma$ a non-identity field automorphism? And then the norms of the two elements are the same, being just products of the conjugates?

Comment: If I have correctly identified $f_1=x-2$ and $f_2=x-4$, then $\sigma(f_1(\zeta_3))=\sigma(\zeta_3-2)=\zeta_3^2-2=-1-\zeta_3-2=-3-\zeta_3\ne\zeta_3-4=f_2(\zeta_3)$, so one of us (probably me) is missing something here. Perhaps Mr Sausage has detected the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one says that $\mathfrak{p} = (p,f_i(x))$ for some factor $f_i(x)$ of $\Phi_n(x) \bmod p$, this doesn't quite make sense, and reflects an an abuse of notation. First of all, $\mathfrak{p}$ is an ideal inside a ring of characteristic zero, so it only makes sense to say that $f_i(x) \in \mathfrak{p}$ if $f_i(x)$ is an element of $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ rather than $\mathbf{F}_p[x]$. So the more precise statement is that $\mathfrak{p} = (p,f_i(x))$ where $f_i(x)$ is *any* polynomial in $\mathbf{Z}[x]$ whose mod-$p$ reduction is a factor of $\Phi_n(x) \bmod p$. The point is that any two choices of lift $f_i(x)$ and $g_i(x)$ will differ by a multiple of $p$, and so the ideals $(p,f_i(x))$ and $(p,g_i(x))$ will be the same.

But in light of this, the original question doesn't make much sense, because the quantity $N_{K/\mathbf{Q}}(f_i(\zeta))$ even for a *single* $i$ is not really well defined and depends on how you choose $f_i(x)$.

As an example, for $n = 4$, you have $x^2 + 1 = (x-2)(x-3) \bmod 5$ and thus (for example) $\mathfrak{p} = (5,i-2)$ is prime, and $N(i-2)= 5$ where $f_1(x) = x - 2$. But you could just as well have taken $f_1(x) = x+3$ and then $\mathfrak{p} = (5,i+3)$ and $N(i+3) = 10$. So the two things you are asking to be equal are themselves not well-defined.

Comment: I see! So the $f_i(x)$ are only defined up to some additive factor divisible by $p$. In that case, is it possible to always choose a set of representatives $f_i(x)$ such that the norms of the $f_i(\zeta_n)$ are equal?

Comment: The norm of $\zeta - a$ is $(a^n - 1)/(a-1)$. The polynomial $P(a) = (a^n-1)/(a-1)$ has either one or zero local minima, and so there can only ever be at most two values of $a$ such that the norm of $\zeta - a$ is the same. So if you insist that $f_i(x) = x - a_i$ and $n \ne 2,3,4,6$ then the answer is no in general.

Comment: That makes sense. One final question: In your example above, you point out that with $f_1(x) = x-2$, $N(i-2)=5$. This choice would give $f_2(x) = x-3$, or $f_2(x) = x+2$. But then $N(i+2) = 5$, and it seems like we have representatives as desired. For any $n$, is it possible to find just two of the possible $\phi(n)$ representatives, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$, such that $N(\frac{f_1(x)}{f_2(x)}) = 1$?